# Building graph from OSM and GTFS data using OTP

Tags: openstreetmap, gtfs, opentripplanner

I have a few questions regarding building graph with OTP ([OpenTripPlanner](https://www.opentripplanner.org/)) containing GTFS data and OSM data. I am using GTFS and OSM data for Berlin.

1. I read [here](https://github.com/marcusyoung/otp-tutorial/blob/master/intro-otp.Rmd) that OTP version 2 does not support isochrone and surface analysis features. This is from November 2021. Has this changed since then?
2. Using the same GTFS and OSM data I am able to build the graph with [OTP v2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/opentripplanner/otp/2.1.0/) but not with [OTP v1.5](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/opentripplanner/otp/1.5.0/). I get an error as shown below while building the graph with OTP v1.5. It seems a field is missing in pathways.txt file. However, before changing any of the GTFS files I would like to know if anyone has had this error and does adding a field will resolve the error?

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" org.onebusaway.csv_entities.exceptions.CsvEntityIOException: io error: entityType=org.onebusaway.gtfs.model.Pathway path=pathways.txt lineNumber=2

   Caused by: org.onebusaway.csv_entities.exceptions.MissingRequiredFieldException: missing required field: pathway_type
   ```

Command used to build the graph:

```
 java -Xmx4G -jar otp-1.5.0-shaded.jar --build graphs/current --port 9090
```

3. I am also trying to start the OTP v1.5 server by loading an already build graph using the switch `--load` but, it throws error `Unknown option --load`.  How can I load an already build graph to start the otp server in version 1.5?